# For what reason is the term "part of sentence" not considered a linguistic standard?

Tags: terminology

Whenever I browse through a book on grammar teaching of a particular language, there is a good chance I'll encounter the term "part of sentence". Actually, I can not remember having peeked into such a book without this term contained. So, at least, in the realm of teaching it is a key-term. But in which respect does this term fail for linguistics?

p.s. is this also the case for part of speech?

Comment: Please remember that the personal pronoun 'I' is always written with a capital letter except,, for some people,  in very informal situations such as chat-rooms or personal texts and emails.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the title, author, and ISBN of the books into which you are peeking?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard the term "part of sentence".

Answer (score 0):

*Part of speech,* sometimes termed *word class* these days, is a recognised term to cover labels such as *noun, verb, adjective*, etc. Though we may speak of 'a part' or  'parts' of a sentence, there is no agreed meaning for a linguistic term 'part of sentence'.

Comment: Then what is the linguistic term that refers to "subject, verb, direct object, indirect object, or prepositional phrase"?

Comment: 'Sentence' is a term that comes out of writing. Linguistics is not typically about writing but about language.  A sentence can be one word, one clause, multiple clauses, etc, so it's a very diverse beast.  For a cover term for the items you list, perhaps 'constituents'?

Comment: @tepples you're mixing several things there. Some are word classes, some are syntactic classes, and the last is a phrase.